# Using "requests" to use bitcoin address balance

Tags: python, bitcoin

I am trying to get the balance of a bitcoin address and use it as a number in the rest of my application:

```
import requests
req = requests.get('http://blockexplorer.com/q/getreceivedbyaddress/19hMEAaRMbEhfSkeU4GT8mgSuyR4t4M6TH/1')

SatoshiConvert = int(req.text) / 100000000
print SatoshiConvert
```

This is resulting in the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "checkBalances.py", line 26, in <module>
SatoshiConvert = int(req.text) / 100000000
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '83.58000000'
```

I think that I am trying to use an object as a number but despite trying to make the transformation, I have been unable to.

EDIT: Thanks to EdChum for the reply. For anyone wondering how to change a bitcoin balance to satoshis I used this code with the above request-

```
SatoshiConvert = int((float(req.text))*100000000)
```

Comment: The error is pretty clear you're trying to cast a string of float to an int, why not cast to float?

Comment: Thanks. I read that using floats isn't advisable from here: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Proper_Money_Handling_%28JSON-RPC%29 Is it a worry in this example? I'm also trying to convert the balance to satoshis from the current balance and it's proving difficult, do you recommend using format to process this?

Comment: You could use [`decimal`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html)